# Verilog range must be bounded by constant expression

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I'm having trouble figuring out how to translate this VHDL code to Verilog.

```
v_Upper     := r_Digit_Index*4 + 3;
v_Lower     := r_Digit_Index*4;
v_BCD_Digit := unsigned(r_BCD(v_Upper downto v_Lower));

if v_BCD_Digit > 4 then
  v_BCD_Digit := v_BCD_Digit + 3;
end if;

r_BCD(v_Upper downto v_Lower) <= std_logic_vector(v_BCD_Digit);
```

If I try doing this in Verilog, I get the error, "Range Must be Bound by Constant Expression."  I understand the error, but I can't figure out a good way to get around this.  Essentially I want to parse a specific nibble of r_BCD, update it if it needs updating, then write it back into the same location that I pulled it from.  Would a 2D array be better here?

Here's the line of Verilog code causing the problem:+

```
r_BCD[r_Digit_Index*4 + 3:r_Digit_Index*4] <= w_BCD_Digit + 3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In verilog you can not have a variable selection like that.

ie `r_BCD[r_Digit_Index*4 + 3:r_Digit_Index*4]` is not allowed.

Since 2001 you can do variable part-select using the special `+:` syntax.

for example :

```
r_BCD[r_Digit_Index*4 +: 4] 
   //[ index          +: width]
```

For more info see [Sutherland 2001 part 1-48](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2001-Wescon-tutorial_using_Verilog-2001_part1.pdf).